# No network traffic after reboot

Tags: networking, server, iptables, firewall

When ever I reboot my machine, I loose network connectivity.  I have to run several commands to restore traffic, both in and out.

This machine has one open port to the internet, and I have Fail2Ban running to protect that port. Root is disabled so I have to Sudo all commands.   This is 16.04 btw. I also have squid running on this machine as a proxy for my children's devices.

I will run:

> iptables -A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT 
>  
>    iptables -A FORWARD ACCEPT
>  
>    iptables -A INPUT ACCEPT 
>   iptables -A OUTPUT ACCEPT

and network connectivity is restored.

I have nuked the firewall settings to set to allow all traffic, and I still have to plug in those commands to restore traffic.

I'm at my wits end any one else have this happen?  Any direction on what to  check would be greatly appreciated, as I'm a novice to Linux.

Comment: Do you have a firewall on your machine?  It sounds like you do and the rules are set up wrong.

Comment: The only  firewall i have turning on is the built in one from ubuntu.  This is set to pass all traffic.

Comment: After re-boot, and before you manually enter your iptabes rules. do this: ` sudo iptables -v -x -n -L` , edit your question adding that output.

Comment: thanks for the tip.

I'm going to close this one out. While lookinng at Logs, I found a Load_Balance.pl script running. I completely forgot about this and when ever the script would run, it was noticing a NIC was down and re-writing IPTables.

Once I removed the script, flushed the IPtables, and reboot, the issue did not surface.